# Coffescript. The second method is not performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Note that only the method "hideHeader" runs. I click the button, the class is usually changed, but the method that is executed is always the "hideHeader".

```
hideHeader = ->
  $(".retract-header a").click ->
    alert 'retract-header'
    $(this).parent().attr("class", "expand-header")

showHeader = ->
  $(".expand-header a").click ->
    alert 'expand-header'
    $(this).parent().attr("class", "retract-header")


$ ->
  'use strict'
  showHeader()
  hideHeader()
```

Comment: Changing the class of an element doesn't change what events and properties said element has. Don't confuse javascript with css.

Comment: You mean to "ShowHeader" make sense, it must be previously defined in a HTML tag?

Comment: No, what i'm saying is when you execute `showHeader`, there are no elements that match `.expand-header a`. that's why that handler never gets triggered. changing the class of the parent element doesnt' change that fact.

Comment: It's true, Kevin. Thank you so much. Forgive the delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

`$(".retract-header a, .expand-header a").click ->
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("retract-header expand-header")`